# How to block other apps to Open .Only My app will be open when android is strated

Tags: applications, development

1) When My app is running disable buttons like home,minimize.

2) only admin can Unlock this feature.

Comment: See [tag:kiosk-mode] tag for ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for LockTask Mode. For more info, see [corporate-owned, single-use setup](https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html)

https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html